# Lock objects in Qt like C#

Tags: c++, qt4, locking

in C# if I have for example a list I could do

```
lock (this.mylist)
{
    ...
}
```

and with that code I'm sure noone else can use the list before releasing the lock. This is useful in multithreaded applications. How can I do the same thing on Qt? I read docs about QMutex and QReadWriteLock but I don't understand how to use them on a specific object.

Comment: C++ in general doesn't have any built-in feature to tie a mutex to a particular object.  You just lock the mutex while you're using the object and unlock it once you're done.

Comment: However, DO use an RAII container that locks the mutex on construction and unlocks it on destruction!  boost::unique_lock is an example of this.

Comment: You are mistaken about what the above C# code does. `this.mylist` *can* be read and written by other parts of the code, it is the *section of code* between the braces that is locked. Only one thread can run this code at a time. The object used to take the lock is just a key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use `QMutex` (or any standard synchronization method in C/C++) all critical sections which rely on each other must know about the mutex. The simplest (yet, not best practice in C++ i.e. make it a class member or something) way to ensure this, is to create a global variable mutex (which we will do for example).

So consider the following

```
QMutex mutex;

void someMethod()
{
  mutex.lock();
  // Critical section
  mutex.unlock();
}
```

Now, `lock` and `unlock` are atomic methods, so only one thread will be able to enter the critical section at any given time. The key is that both are trying to access the *same* mutex.

So in essence, this works the same way as `C#` except you need to manage your mutex yourself. So the `lock(...) { ... }` block is replaced by `mutex.lock() ... mutex.unlock()`. This also implies, however, that anytime you want to access the critical section items (i.e. in your example, `this->mylist`), you should be using the mutex.

**EDIT**
Qt has very good documentation. You can read more about `QMutex` here: http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qmutex.html

Comment: and If I need to lock multiple lists? Should I call lock/unlock only one time for all in the method or should I call multiple lock/unlock? And should I have a different QMutex for each list?

Comment: The idea is to keep the critical section as small as possible, however, anytime you want to read/write to a particular element use a mutex (if this element is shared across threads). Now, you do not necessarily need a mutex per list. That is, if you always read one list and write to the other (or any permutation of that) at the same time, you can use one mutex and manipulate both lists at once.

Comment: Worth to mention QMutexLocker here

Answer (score 2):

The general C++ way to do things like this is using RAII, so you wind up with code like this:

```
// Inside a function, a block that needs to be locked
{
  QMutexLocker lock(&mutex); // locks mutex
  // Do stuff

  // "QMutexLocker" destructor unlocks the mutex when it goes out of scope
}
```

I don't know how that translates to Qt, but you could probably write a helper class if there's no native support.

EDIT: Thanks to Cory, you can see that Qt supports this idiom very nicely.

Comment: QMutexLocker is the Qt class for that.

Answer (score 0):

In C++11 you can do this:

```
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>

std::mutex mut;

void someMethod()
{
  std::lock_guard(mut);
  // Critical section
}
```

This is the RAII idiom - the lock guard is an object that will release the lock no matter how someMethod scope is exited (normal return or throw).  See C++ concurrency In Action by Anthony Williams.  He also has a [C++11 thread implementation](http://www.stdthread.co.uk/).  The C++11 implementation is much like the boost thread implementation.